# It looks like this website is copying Mathematica SE questions automatically

Tags: discussion

A user in the comment section of [this Mathematica SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181893/asymptotic-density-of-twin-primes-gives-wrong-result-in-mathematica?noredirect=1#comment474932_181893) noticed that the question also appeared on another website:

http://mathematics.filegala.com/2018/09/14/asymptotic-density-of-twin-primes-gives-wrong-result-in-mathematica/

Actually, it appears that this website is actively copying posts from Mathematica SO and pasting them there. Is there something that SE can do in such a situation?